# Does a composite INDEX work for JOINING (MANY to MANY)?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, query-optimization

**tt** - is a mapping table.
**tt** structure is

**table_1 | table_2 | table_3**

```
   SELECT t1.foo1, t2.foo2, t3.foo3 FROM tt 
        JOIN table1 t1 ON tt.table_1 = t1.id
        JOIN table2 t2 ON tt.table_2 = t2.id
        JOIN table3 t3 ON tt.table_3 = t3.id
    WHERE t2.value = 'test'
```

Does the index has a sense and will be working for `tt`?
The composite index is `ix_table_1__table_2__table_3(table1, table2, table_3)`

If do - why, if don't - why?

Comment: Never use evil `SELECT *`

Comment: It goes double for demos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I disagree with the indexes recommended in another Answer.)

```
SELECT * FROM tt 
    JOIN table1 t1 ON tt.table_1 = t1.id
    JOIN table2 t2 ON tt.table_2 = t2.id
    JOIN table3 t3 ON tt.table_3 = t3.id
WHERE t2.value = 'test'
```

When the Optimizer picks how to execute a `JOIN`, it *usually* works like this:

1. Start with the table with the best `WHERE`.  This would be `t2`.  So there needs to be an `INDEX` *starting* with `value`.
2. Then move on to each other table.  The only next choice is `tt`, due to the `ON` clause this time.
3. After that `t1` and `t3`, in either order.

Now for the indexes, listed in the order above:

```
t2:  INDEX(value)
tt:  INDEX(table_2)
```

`t1` and `t3` are accessed via their `id`.  So, assuming you follow the convention of `id` being the PK, then `PRIMARY KEY(id)` is already there.

Now let's switch to the new version of the query:

```
SELECT t1.foo1, t2.foo2, t3.foo3 FROM tt  ...
```

With that, we can make better indexes.  A "covering" index is an `INDEX` that includes all the columns needed anywhere in the query.  So, let's tack on any such columns:

```
t2:  INDEX(value, id, foo2)
tt:  INDEX(table_2, table_3, table_1)  -- table_2 must be first
```

Two things to note when thinking about a "covering" index:

- When reaching into a table via the `PRIMARY KEY`, there is no advantage in making a "covering" index.  The PK is "clustered" with the data, hence effectively 'covering'.
- It is not 'wise' to have too many columns in an index.  You are asking for all (`*`) columns.

More on creating optimal indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Alas, `EXPLAIN` shows what is done with what is available; it does not should what indexes should be added, nor other tips.

Your tables do not look like traditional many:many tables.  See this for specific tips on that type of table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

`FOREIGN KEYs`:  A FK provides (1) a constraint (for data integrity) and (2) an `INDEX` to make checking that constraint efficient.  When you create both an FK *and* an `INDEX`, MySQL *may* be smart enough to avoid having 2 indexes when only suffices.  `INDEX(table_2)` is all that the FK needs, but `INDEX(table_2, table_3, table_1)` will "work" for that FK.  Having both indexes is a waste; drop the shorter one if it is unnecessarily added.

Comment: @rick-james **1-** Why do we need `INDEX(table_2)` in the first case; if the convention is in place and `table_2` is indeed a FK to `table2`. Doesn't MySQL (InnoDB) index FKs? **2-** Can you elaborate on the `INDEX(table_2, table_3, table_1)` in the latter case? I see the need for `INDEX(value, id, foo2)` but...

Comment: @HasanCanSaral - See if my addition about FKs addresses your concerns.

Comment: Thank you. I get it (at least the first part) now. I'm specifically asking for [this case](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283439/how-do-i-add-composite-mysql-indexes-with-denormalization-and-joins). The need for composite indexes on JOINSs. I really appreciate your work and help. Thank you.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral - Thanks for starting a new Question; it is sufficiently distinct from this one to warrant a separate discussion.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tt 
    JOIN table1 t1 ON tt.table_1 = t1.id
    JOIN table2 t2 ON tt.table_2 = t2.id
    JOIN table3 t3 ON tt.table_3 = t3.id
WHERE t2.value = 'test'
```

Yes, an index on `tt(table_1, table_2, table_3)` could be beneficial.

You also want indexes on the following columns:

```
t1(id)
t2(id, value)
t3(id)
```

As commented by spencer7593, you might also want to try `t2(value, id)` instead of `t2(id, value)`. If `id` is the primary key as it looks like, the former should be much more efficient as it could be used to pre-filter the records in the `where` clause and efficently limit the number of rows to join.

Whether indexes will or not be useful depends on lots of factors such as the relative size of your tables and the distribution of values within columns (or what the query planner assesses on this criteria). You do want to use `EXPLAIN` and analyze the results.

Comment: Thanks for your help, EXPLAIN doesn't help me, cause it show only possible keys,
but if I recreate the composite index and rearrange table_1, table_2, table_3 - I also see this as possible keys. It is the problem with EXPLAIN. EXPLAIN doesn't explain enouph what happens.

Comment: for this query, i'd be tempted to go with an index on t2 that has `value` as the leading column (because of the equality condition) and include `id` to make it a covering index  "`... on table2 (value,id)`".  and then an index on tt with `table_2` as the  leading column  "`... on tt (table_2, ...)`"

Comment: @spencer7593: that's a good point, thank you. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Also, the `tt` index is sub-optimal.  I elaborate in my answer.

Comment: @GMB - In many situations, the order of the columns in an `INDEX` matters.  (t2 and tt in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

If the three fields are always together then a composite makes sense.

but in your case you nees alsol one single for t2.value